# Confusing C++ global scope issues

Tags: c++, scope, declaration, global

I am taking a C++ practice test and I'm confused with a set of access scope and point of declaration related questions. Both the  questions are related to each other..I know the answers..what i need is proper explanation :

What is the value of the local variable x at the end of main

```
 int x = 5;
 int main(int argc, char** argv)
 {
    int x = x;
    return 0;
 }
```

ans: Undefined

What is the value of y at the end of main?

```
    const int x = 5;
    int main(int argc, char** argv)
    {
       int x[x];
       int y = sizeof(x) / sizeof(int);
       return 0;
    }
```

answer: 5

Answer (score 8):

It's controlled by when the inner `x` comes into existence (the start of its scope). The standard states (3.3.1 in the current standard, 3.3.2 in the upcoming one) in part (my italics):

> The point of declaration for a name is immediately *after* its complete declarator and *before* its initializer.

With `int x = x;`, it's created at the point of the `=` so that when you assign `x` to it, that's the *inner* x which is being used. Since that hasn't been set to anything before, it's undefined.

With `int x[x];`, the inner `x` comes into existence at the `;` so it's using the outer `x` as the array size.

Answer (score 8):

From the standard: 3.3.1 [basic.scope.pdecl]

> The *point of declaration* for a name is immediately after its complete declarator (clause 8) and before its *initializer* (if any), except as noted below.

The standard even has two examples to clarify this:

```
int x = 12;
{ int x = x; }
```

> Here the second `x` is initialized with its own (indeterminate) value.
>
> [Note: a nonlocal name remains visible up to the point of declaration of the local name that hides it. [Example:

```
const int i = 2;
{ int i[i]; }
```

> declares a local array of two integers. ]]

These two examples cover the two cases in your question.